# Missing Refrence Plugins of NopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.3

I have added some Compiled Plugins Such as : "Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal","Tax.Avalara" and ...
to "Presentation/Nop.Web/Plugins" but did not installed succeesfully, I tried following:

clean "Presentation/Nop.web/bin"

clean "Presentation/Nop.Web/Plugins/bin"

clean and Rebuild My Suoltion

but Not Work !
I Also tried Add Source of Plugins to `"NopCommerce/Plugins"` and set correct output directory then build plugin
I Also tried install plugin from admin panel
but non of above not work for me !
any one can help me what can i do to solve this ?
Important Note: I use 4.3.0 version and all plugins are 4.3.0 version

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows,I found the Solution